# Errors with INSERT ... ON CONFLICT

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I have this code below

```
INSERT INTO table1 (code, value)
VALUES ('code1', 'value1')
ON CONFLICT (code, value)
WHERE code = 'code1'
  DO
    UPDATE SET value = 'value1';
```

When I try running this code I get

```
ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

So I tried adding a "where" clause in the "update" part, but then I get the error

```
ERROR: column reference "code" is ambiguous
```

How to correctly create an "insert" with "do update"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the `WHERE` condition is thrown because it is not clear if you mean `table1.code` (the old version) or `EXCLUDED.code` (the new version). You have to be explicit there.

But that `WHERE` condition won't do anything to prevent the original problem, namely that there is no unique constraint or index on `(code, value)`. You have to create such a constraint or index if you want to use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`.

Comment: is there a way i can get the ID of the old table and use it in where clause of the update table ? if so can i just use `id` meaning that this is ID of the old table since `EXCLUDE.id` would be the `id` of new table?

Comment: I tried something like `WHERE excluded.id = id;` still i get `[42702] ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous` is there a way to do like this ?

Comment: Any unqualified `id` is ambiguous, as my answer explains. Focus on the unique constraint that you need to create, then you can worry about the correct `WHERE`.